# Getting issue while calling Model predict function on Keras for Numpy multi dimension array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Code prediction working for h5 simple predict()

[image]

Same model giving error while doing numpy array row wise lambda call

[image]

Keras model trained for timeseries problem with sliding window approach where based on past 60 timesteps, i am generating the 61st timestamp value for multi dimension (4 features). Simple model.predict() is working fine. Test Data is in numpy.array format.
But i am looking to optimize this predict call and thinking maybe np.apply_along_axis function would give better performance with parallel operation.

Comment: If you share the code, we can help. But we cannot try anything on the image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.